# Handling http errors

Tags: angular, http

I've implemented service function in following way:

```
addStopped(factoryNum: string): Observable<HttpResponse<null | ErrorMsg>> {
    return this.httpClient.put<null>(environment.stopListUrl + `/${factoryNum}/add`, null, {observe: "response"});
  }

export class ErrorMsg {
  error: string;
}
```

This route respond with 204 code if succeed or with 400 and `{"error":"error msg"}` if fails. I was trying to handle it simply checking status code:

```
this.stopListService.addStopped(this.inputVal).subscribe((response) => {
      response.ok ? this.getStopped():console.log( "!!!", response.status, response.body.error)
    });
```

But somewhy I don't get the message I'm trying to log, only these messages:
[image]

Comment: Use interceptors or `(err)=>{ //custom error message }`

Answer (score 0):

The response is already parsed if it is a JSON request. Subscribe takes two argument, success and error

```
this.stopListService.addStopped(this.inputVal).subscribe(
  handleSuccessObjectFunction,
  handleErrorFunction
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle success and error case in different handlers:

```
this.stopListService.addStopped(this.inputVal).subscribe((response) => {//success
      // do something
    }, (error) => { // error
console.log( "!!!", response.status, response.body.error); // check if the error is inside the body or just response.error or response.error.message or response.error.error; this also depends upon your BE service implementation, if you have changed it.
});
```